# Direct boot to a named USB device

Tags: boot, usb, grub2, bootloader

Is there a method for adding an option line in the GRUB loader (Ubuntu 10.10) that directs the boot specifically to a named USB device? If so, can you provide an example of the line to add? This is for use in an office environment where people would prefer to select their boot options from a menu.

Comment: One problem I foresee with adding that to GRUB would be that the system might not boot correctly if a user forgets to put the USB device into the system.  It may also just not work if it can't find the uuid of the device in question on load of GRUB.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is, but at the moment I can only find reference material on booting by uuid like so: http://grumpymole.blogspot.com/2007/05/ubuntu-how-to-edit-grub-boot-parameters.html  I will update my answer if I run across a label= example

edit:if you want to boot a kernel image off of a specified device i am still at a loss atm, but here's a link for root fs by label: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/23010-root-label-grub-conf.html

they reference redhat based distros liking this approach and i used to be a redhat guy, so i can't tell you if this is redhat dependent or not.  i go with uuids in my current situations

this guy wrote a patch a LONG time ago: http://osdir.com/ml/boot-loaders.grub.bugs/2004-02/msg00105.html

looks like the invocation is: kernel /PATHTOKERNEL ro root=LABEL=MOUNTPOINT